# Creating a list of items, assign them id and than make a option button with overlay with multiple options

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm working on a list of items for my website.

I have a list of 5 items with a 'id'. When you click the button, an overlay must be shown with 2 buttons 'change to background to red' and than 'cancel'.
If you click the cancel, the specific 'div class="item"' with the specific id his background must become red.

But, the problem is I don't know how using jquery/javascript to know which button of the div what pressed (button of item id 1 or 2 or 3..)
And also when you click outside the buttons, the overlay must be removed.

Here's the code

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
    $('.options-btn').click(function ()
    {
        var id = $(this).parent().attr('id'); /* find <div class="item"> */
        $('body').append('<div class="overlay"></div>');

        var append = `
            <div class="item-options-active">
                <button class="feed-option-btn-number background-btn" tabindex="0">Background set to RED</button>
                <button class="feed-option-btn-number cancel-btn" tabindex="0">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        `;

        $(append).appendTo('.overlay');
    });


    $(document).click(function (e)
    {
        if (document.getElementsByClassName("overlay").length == 1)
        {
            if(document.getElementsByClassName("item-options-active").length == 1)
            {
                // this condition is not working when you click the specific button
                if($(".background-btn").data('clicked'))
                {
                    // how to get <div> of the button which was press to change the background??
                    $('.item').css('background', 'red');
                }
            }
        }
    });
    
})
```

```css
body {
  background: grey;
}

.item {
  background: green;
  border: 5px solid purple;
  
  margin: 20px;
}

.item button {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.85);
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="show-items">
    <div class="item" id="1">
        <button type="button" class="options-btn">check options</button>
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="2">
        <button type="button" class="options-btn">check options</button>
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="3">
        <button type="button" class="options-btn">check options</button>
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="4">
        <button type="button" class="options-btn">check options</button>
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="5">
        <button type="button" class="options-btn">check options</button>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you rewrite the .option-btn click event to something like this and delete the document click event it should work:

```
$('.options-btn').click(function ()
    {
        var id = $(this).parent().attr('id'); /* find <div class="item"> */
        var button = $(this);
        $('body').append('<div class="overlay"></div>');

        var append = `
            <div class="item-options-active">
                <button class="feed-option-btn-number background-btn" tabindex="0">Background set to RED</button>
                <button class="feed-option-btn-number cancel-btn" tabindex="0">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        `;

        $(append).appendTo('.overlay');
        
        $('.overlay').on('click', function(){
            $(this).remove();
        }).find('.cancel-btn').on('click', function(){
            $(this).closest('.overlay').remove();
        });

        $('.overlay').find('.background-btn').on('click', function(){
            button.closest('.item').css('background', 'red');
          $(this).closest('.overlay').remove();
        });
});
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qntupzj6/

Comment: Is working, but if I click the overlay (outside the button) the overlay must be removed (is like clicking the cancel button)